# DynamoDB query filter on list count

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm pretty new to DynamoDB and have some questions, I have a table with some products, where each product can have multiple prices.

I need a way to get all products with more the one price, how do I do that?

```
hash = url ( unique )
sort = vendor
```

Example data:

```
{
  "created_at": "2018-11-29T14:33:20.354895+0000",
  "vendor": "example.com",
  "url": "http://example.com/test",
  "name": "test product",
  "prices": [
    {
      "created_at": "2018-11-29T14:33:20.316396+0000",
      "price": 29
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2018-11-28T14:33:20.316396+0000",
      "price": 45
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Tell us what are the partition and eventually sorting keys, please. If I understand well your example you're not using the benefits of dynamodb as you could and should do.

Comment: Arh,, sorry, i just added in the data.

Comment: @Costin see my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your table model I do not know how to answer your question. But I can suggest you another model. :)

The problem with your model is that you want to query `length(prices)`. As far as I know DynamoDB does not return that value by itself.

I suggest you to create:

- a column `nprices : number`,
- a GSI (global secondary index) with the hash of your choice and a range key that starts with the `nprices`. Example: hash = url, range = nprices_vendor.

You may query the database with something like:

```
db.query({
  TableName: 'MY_TABLE_NAME',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#pk = :pk AND #sk > :skLow', # lexicographical comparison
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#pk': 'url', # partition key
    '#sk': 'nprices_vendor', # sorting key
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':pk': 'http://example.com', 
    ':skLow': '2',
  },
```

}).promise()

**But** this is still not the best solution. What you should do is to modify your table and have each price on its own row. That is another problem. :)

Comment: price pr. row solution may not work, because I also want the timestamp for the price.. but updating a row with price count would work, thanks ;)